# How to add JMenuBar shortcuts?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Adding shortcuts to JMenuBar submenu items in the Java Swing GUI designer is obvious, but how are shortcuts added to JMenuBar main menu items?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do it programatically or through the GUI designer?  If the GUI designer, what IDE are you using?  Is this Netbeans?

Comment: I would like to know how to do it programatically?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two types of keyboard shortcuts: mnemonics and accelerators.

Mnemonics are usually triggered using Alt+KEY. That's the letter that's underlined in the menu item text (F for File, for example). Accelerators are application-wide shortcuts that are usually triggered using Ctrl+KEY.

---

To use mnemonics, you can use the `setMnemonic()` method:

```
menuItem.setMnemonic('F');
```

---

To use accelerators, you have to use the `setAccelerator()` method.

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
        java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, 
        java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK));
```

Comment: Thanks. `menuItem.setMnemonic('F');` did exactly what was needed.

Comment: Note that `setMnemonic` always uses the first occurrence of the letter (see `SwingUtilities#findDisplayedMnemonicIndex`). If you need to use a latter occurrence, use `AbstractButton#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex`, which corresponds to `Action.DISPLAYED_MNEMONIC_INDEX_KEY`. (BTW I recommend you set action properties then call `AbstractButton#setAction` instead of calling those JComponent methods directly.)

Comment: What is the different between accelerator and setMnemonic?

Comment: am having a problem when using this on a `JMenuItem` in a `JPopupMenu` it wont work unless i press on the `JPopupMenu` and the dropdown of options appears and then while its shown it will work how can i go make the shortcut work without the need to press and show scenario

Answer (score 2):

The Sun/Oracle site has a great Tutorial on using [JMenu's](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)
When you are dealing with shortcut keys, Java uses mnemonic or Accelerator depending on the shortcut you want to use.
you can set the mnemonic using the following

```
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

and the accelerator via

```
 menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                        KeyEvent.VK_T, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
```

These are both examples taken from the link above